# Opencv assertion fail mat.hpp line 416

Tags: c++, windows, opencv

I am getting this error at this point of the code:

```
matcher.match(descriptors, possible_planes_it->back().getDescriptor(), matches);
```

However this statement is within a for loop and got executed around 30 times before it crashes.

The exact meassage is:

First: 
http://www.pic-upload.de/view-21954202/Unbenannt.jpg.html

Cmd output:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (y == 0 || (data && dims >= 1 && (unsigned)y < (unsigned)size.p[0])) in cv::Mat::ptr, file C:..../core/mat.hpp, line 416
```

How can I find out if something is wrong with the descriptors, which obviously must cause this error, or am I completely wrong? Checking if the descriptors are empty or things like that did not help.

Comment: can you post the whole for loop? FYI: one of your `possible_planes_it` is causing the error, not `descriptors`

Comment: Before you need to guesstemate too much you can find the whole sourcecode here: main: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qeiu51irqlxig6i/main.cpp include: https://www.dropbox.com/s/unrwfsiaq3r6yy6/Plane.cpp header: https://www.dropbox.com/s/q6yqr4jpd8nhuew/Plane.h

Comment: Please not that the line directly above works. So the iterator seems to work just fine.

Comment: Ill take a look when I have time. First sight: isn't std::back() used with vectors (not iterators)? not sure though.

Comment: Thanks! Well I am just using the iterator to access elements from the list of vectors. I am pretty sure I am actually accessing the vector with the iterator.